# How do I set the friction properties (or any GeometryProperties) of a specific body in MultibodyPlant?

Tags: drake

I would like to know how I can set the frictional properties of a body in `MultibodyPlant`.

More specifically, I have a model instance that has been read in from an SDF and I would like to add or change the friction properties of a particular body in that model instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to set the frictional properties. In addition to your very specific question, I'm going to outline multiple workflows. (As a side note, while some of this is documented, it isn't necessarily discoverable -- or even rendered -- in the doxygen. That's an outstanding issue that needs to be addressed, for which an issue exists).

- Define in the urdf/sdf.

  - Drake provides custom tags associated contact properties (including friction and more) with the `<geometry>` tag. The tags are the same across URDF/SDF but are exercised slightly differently (based on the style of SDF vs URDF). Details can be found [here for sdf](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/parsing/detail_scene_graph.h#L124-L173) and
    [here for urdf](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/parsing/detail_urdf_geometry.h#L137-L197).
- Add new geometry via the API and include friction in the definition.

  - MultibodyPlant has an API for assigning geometry to a body. There are multiplpe variants:

    - [Adding a geometry to a body and explicitly defining the friction](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a602bd19cfdb283686f9051b674611baa)

      - This is a legacy sugar API. Favor the API that takes `ProximityProperties` as the preferred API.
    - [Generally defining ProximityProperties](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#ac9b4f41a4f2575707d43ea031ce5a9ea)

      - In this case, the only question is, where do my proximity properties come from?

  ```cpp
  #include "drake/geometry/proximity_properties.h"
  #include "drake/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h"

  // Omitting drake:: namespaces for clarity.
  MultibodyPlant<double> plant;
  // Populate plant with bodies.   
  ProximityProperties contact_props;
  AddContactMaterial({}, {}, CoulombFriction<double>(mu_s, mu_d), &contact_props);
  // Assume we've defined body, X_BG, shape, and name elsewhere.
  plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(body, X_BG, shape, name, contact_props);
  ```
- Add/Update to geometry defined in a urdf/sdf

  - In this case, we need to change the geometry definition in `SceneGraph` based on its association with a body. That means, starting with the `Body`, we need to get the `GeometryId`. We're going to assume that has been done and you have the `GeometryId` for this workflow.

  ```cpp
  SceneGraph<double> sg;
  const GeometryId g_id = ...;
  CoulombFriction<double> friction(mu_s, mu_d);
  ProximityProperties new_props;
  const ProximityProperties* curr_props = 
      sg.model_inspector().GetProximityProperties(g_id);
  if (curr_props != nullptr) {
    new_props = *curr_props;
  }
  // Replaces old friction definition, or adds it if previously absent.
  new_props.UpdateProperty("material", "coulomb_friction", friction);
  sg.AssignRole(g_id, new_props, RoleAssign::kReplace);
  ```

Comment: Note: the issue for making all of this more discoverable is: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13314

Comment: Let me just add that this is thanks to the incredible effort from Joe Masterjohn in 13630 precisely per your reques @samzapo! working on body parameters now :-)